# encrypt 3 variable value and pass to new page to decrypt

Tags: php

For example:

```
$package = "Gold";

$code    = "abc1234";

$vcode   = "23ffggd45";
```

**Question**: How can I encrypt this 3 variable value with md5 or other encrypt function and pass through to other pages to decrypt the data with same this 3 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();  
$package = "Gold";
$package =md5($package);
$_SESSION['$package']=$package;

$code    = "abc1234";
$code    =md5($code);
$_SESSION['$code']=$code;

$vcode   = "23ffggd45";
$vcode   =md5($vcode);
$_SESSION['$vcode']=$vcode;

//<----(OTHER PAGE)---->
on other pages, you need to put session_start(); on top. 

$package=$_SESSION['$package'];//this 3 variable will be the encrypted variable

$code=$_SESSION['$code'];

$vcode=$_SESSION['$vcode'];
```

You cant decrypt back, unless you use $_SESSION['ur_variable'] before the encryption. It is a one way function, once md5 encrypted, no way to decrypt back.